# It is possible to connect amplifier output of speakers to my PC?

Tags: audio, sound-card, amplification

Can I connect the sound that was destinated to speakers from an amplifier to a PC sound card line-in? Won't my sound card burn?
I don't have any other outputs on amplifier (line-out or headphones) and I don't have any other way to obtain that sound.
Thanks

Comment: The linked answer uses the 3.5mm headphone jack, not the 8ohm terminals.

Comment: @davidpostill
My question was not answered there, because **"I don't have any other outputs on amplifier (line-out or headphones) and I don't have any other way to obtain that sound"** and that answer "use the headphone output of the Yamaha to the line in of the sound card"

Comment: Reopened ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging a powered / speaker output from an amplifier into a line-in jack will likely cause damage, plugging into a microphone input ***will*** cause permanent damage.

Many modern sound cards can deal with line-in and microphone signals using a single connector and a configuration option in the driver.

It *is possible* to turn down the volume, and connect the signal from an amplifier output to a line-level input, however, it will likely sound terrible.

- With a speaker connected, the signal will be distorted by the load from the speaker, the speaker's voice coil, and possibly other things.
- Without a speaker connected, the signal / voltage will likely be much higher, distorted due to the lack of load, and may permanently damage your equipment.

---

There are three common audio level types, it's a ***very good idea*** to ensure that you match these between your equipment.

- High imepdance

  - Typically in the milivolt range, requires a pre-amp
  - e.g: electric guitar, some microphones, etc...
- [Low impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level)

  - Typically 1-2v peak, low-current source
  - e.g: line-level, headphones, some microphones, etc...
- Active

  - Typically in the 10s of Volts (or higher) fed into a low impedance sink (4Ω - 8Ω) with the ability to deliver considerable current
  - e.g: output of amplifier to speakers

[image: signal path example]

Within each of these there are then a number of common ranges - for example, there is a substantial difference (+40%) between "*Consumer Line-Level*" and "*Studio Line-Level*".

[image: line level ranges]

---

Equipment exists to convert between these levels, for example a ["*DI*" (Direct Input)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DI_unit) converts between line-level to high-impedance.

It's less common to convert powered / speaker outputs to line-level, but it is possible and will typically involve an audio transformer to put some load on the amplifier and also reduce the signal level. I've never seen a "*real*" name for these, but search for "*High to Low Level Converter*", and you'll probably come up with a product aimed at car audio. Be careful, as the cheaper options are often limited to a fairly low power (<15W).

[image: transformer]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're answer is the one I was looking for.